# How do I factory reset when my Sprint LG phone that won't boot?

Tags: factory-reset

I have a Sprint LG model# LS670.

When turning on the power it just displays the Android logo in a loop.

How do I factory reset it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure the device isn't connected to power through the usb.
2. Take out the battery if the device is on to turn it off.
3. Put the battery back in.
4. For about 10 seconds hold the volume up, home key, and the power button to turn it back on. Keep holding until the Android system recovery menu loads.
5. Use the volume down button to navigate to wipe data/factory reset
6. Press the button with 4 squares (menu).
7. Another menu will appear to confirm you want to wipe the data. Use the volume to navigate down to Yes and press the menu button.
8. Reboot the phone through the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  Started 1.5 months ago and after rebooting 5 times and taking it to the store (they charged it only) it worked well until today.  I took it back to the store and they told me I needed to replace it. They placed the order for a new phone that will not arrive until next week Tuesday.  Well I read in a blog of LG4 with different carriers not to give up with rebooting that is what I did (including removing the memory card - sometimes the cards get corrupted), I must have rebooted about 12 times and now my cellphone works again.  I was able to back up all my pictures, videos, etc.  Guys, do not give up rebooting.  I know now this will happen again therefore ordering a replacement is just a matter of time.  At least back up all the files you want on a weekly basis.